# Java Bukkit - Invalid plugin.yml

Tags: java, bukkit

When I try to use this `plugin.yml` for a Bukkit plugin:

```
main: me.tommy.kit.Kit
name: Kit
version: 0.1
author: Tommywells123
description: Gives kits!
```

I get the following error:

```
[11:35:18 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/Kit.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:150) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:133) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:357) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:799) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:288) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:23) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:180) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:703) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:690) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.aB(DedicatedServer.java:296) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:261) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:558) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:469) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-59-g6efeddf-b3074jnks]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 12):

This is because you do not have a `plugin.yml` in your export:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml
```

First off, check your spelling, make sure that it is **EXACTLY** `plugin.yml`, which is *CasE-SEnSITivE*.

Next, make sure that your `plugin.yml` is NOT in any packages, but in your `src` directory. I've made that mistake before. Here's what it should look like if you're using Eclipse:

[image]

If that isn't the problem, you may have a corrupted project, try copying all of your packages over to a new projecect (just drag and drop them if you're using eclipse)

Comment: Thanks. I put it in the package.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, the plugin.yml is not actually in the jar.  If you are in eclipse make sure you check that you want to export with the plugin.yml [image: Shows where to check to make sure you have the plugin.yml]

Answer (score 2):

In your project you should see a folder called resources. Make sure that your plugin.yml is placed inside of that.

For example, you may see a folder structure like this: src/main/resources

Once you have it saved in that location, build the file and test it out. THis should resolve the error, but if not then you have something else wrong with the project. Which if that's the case, please post a screenshot of your folder structure for the project.

Comment: Only if he uses Maven.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and what i did was to drag the `plugin.yml` into your project again. this is an example how its not supposed to be

[image]

and if looks like that just drag it into your project as i said so it looks like this [image]

and now when u export u will find `plugin.yml` there

Answer (score 1):

Change `version: 0.1` to `version: 0.1.0` (it becomes a String instead an int), it should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Do not put it in the src/ folder, but in the project folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error for several hours (when doing some basic code tests). I rearranged my plugin.xml (look picture) and when exporting I don't see plugin.xml in selections it but works(plugin loads without errors).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo6LN.jpg

Some setting changes:

Changed Eclipse text file encoding to UTF-8 and new text file line delimiter to other:  Unix. (toolbar -> window -> preferences -> workspace)

Also used notepad++ EOL conversion to Unix (LF). Windows CRLF does not work it just gives an error with plugin.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, before exporting your project, click on project folder in Eclipse Workspace and press F5. It will "sync" the files in your project and plugin.yml would be exported as well.

Answer (score -4):

Where your plugin.yml says version: do 1.0 not 0.1 that should fix it also try what jojodmo said.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with a version "0.1". In fact, it's probably good practice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Change_significance